# How would a humanoid be affected by its quadrupedal-style arms?

Tags: xenobiology, fauna, anatomy, humanoid, bones

Humans have horizontal shoulders. We can do all kinds of stuff with them, but what would it be like if we had vertical shoulders like a quadrupedal animal, specifically, a cat? What movements could the arm make/not make, such as throwing and rotating the arm?

[image: This is a cat's skeleton.]

[image: This is a human skeleton! One of our own.]

Cats and humans have drastically different skeletons, but I'm focusing on the shoulders and possible lack of clavicle.

Comment: A dog's shoulders, for example, are placed different compared to a humans. Here are some pictures showing the comparison. https://www.worldwideboxer.com/graphics/skeleton-front.jpg https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/108/posts/31371/image/how-to-draw-skeleton-5-2.png

Comment: I didn't know that! :O

Comment: There are *major* differences between the way the forelimbs are attached to the body in primates and in the Carnivora. The bones are just a part of it: muscles and tendons are different too. As primates, we can move our arms freely in all directions, whereas carnivorans have much more restricted freedom. As primates adapted for brachiation, our arms can support our body weight under the body, above the body or sideways from the body (hang by our arms from tree branches, pull ourselves from a side) whereas the joints of carnivorans are mostly able to bear loads with the limbs under the body.

Comment: ... As primates, we can rotate our forearms along their axis about 270°: this allows us to grip and pull objects with our palms upwards, downwards, inwards or outwards; carnivorans basically can only rotate their forearms about 90°, their palms facing either down on inwards. Overall, the skeleton of us primates is much closer to our (para-)reptilian ancestors then the skeleton of carnivorans, which is highly specialized for their lifestyle. We are generalists, they are specialists.

Comment: Andrea I. Alton already wrote [a book](https://www.amazon.com/Demon-Undoing-Andrea-I-Alton/dp/0671654136) wherein the main inhabitants have exactly this problem.

Comment: [Does this help answer your question at all?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207749/would-there-be-problems-in-a-humanoid-with-non-simian-shoulders/207793#207793)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would there be problems in a humanoid with non-simian shoulders?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207749/would-there-be-problems-in-a-humanoid-with-non-simian-shoulders)

Comment: "Cats and humans have drastically different skeletons, but I'm focusing on the shoulders and possible lack of clavicle." - once i saw how a cat had opened a door using door-handle. He stood on his hind legs, reached for the handle with his front paws and opened the door. I think you will be interested in items of circus training. Bears can ride bicycles and motorcycles, and so on ... youtu.be/4LcMz614d18 _____ much also depends on the development of the hand; Сhimpanzees move horizontally most of the time - but can do almost anything that humans do

Answer (score 1):

**Depends on how much humanoid are the things for you**

What is a humanoid for you specifically?

For me a baboon have a very humanoid look.
[image]

But even with that have a posture more adapted to the quadrupedalism and maybe more comparable with felines and canines.

[image]

This could deplete their tool manipulating abilities compared with other primates but not in a really significant way.

[image]